# How to get a zoomed out background image?

Tags: html, css

So on my page here: dunnrite.co.uk/frame2 you will find under the "text design" header some patterns beneath the 5 solid blocks of colour. They are set as background images for divs. The problem is because I want those divs so small it clips a load off of the original image. How do I get it so that the image shown is more zoomed out to show off the pattern more?

My css was just

```
background-image:url("Images/pattern12.jpg");
```

Thanks,

Jonathan

Comment: Any code you want to share...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `background-size` CSS property, and probably you want to use the `cover` value, which ensures that the background completely covers your container, without distorting the image (if the aspect ratio differs, then clipping will occur).

You can also specify an explicit size for your background image, for example 45px as in your case.

The documentation for `background-size` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Perfect. I added -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;

Answer (score 0):

I zoom in the element using the transform: scale(2,2); property.

here is demo link ..
http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/4/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div>
    <p>hello</p>
</div>


html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.wrap {
    height: 33%;
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div.wrap > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background-image: url('http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00288122/b/0/Our-Valuable-Client-List-Click-on-Image-.jpg');
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.wrap:hover > div {
    -moz-transform: scale(2,2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2,2);
    transform: scale(2,2);    
}
```